# Declaring an object without using the namespace of the class

Tags: vb.net, import, namespaces

I have a class library project named `MyWidget`, with the only class being named `MyWidget`.

In another project, I've added a reference to my class library, and in my new class, I've tried typing in

```
Imports MyWidget
```

and

```
Imports MyWidget.MyWidget
```

However, later in my class when I try to create a new reference, Visual Studio is not allowing me to type in this:

```
Private widget As MyWidget
```

However, Visual Studio is giving me a "Type Expected." error and forcing me to also include the namespace, like so:

```
Private widget As MyWidget.MyWidget
```

I read the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f38zh8x.aspx) regarding the `Imports` statement. I should be able to leave off the namespace when declaring the object because I have the imports statement at the top of the program. I've tested this with standard namespaces, and it works fine, but when I try it out with my class, it doesn't.

Am I missing something in the `MyWidget` class that will allow me to leave off the namespace when declaring the object?

I also tried renaming the namespace to `MyClasses`, thinking maybe that Visual Studio was getting the namespace confused with the class. However, even with

```
Imports MyClasses.MyWidget
```

I still get an error when trying to define a `MyWidget` object without the `MyClasses` Namespace.

Comment: Are you adding the `Imports MyWidget` statement at the top of every file that uses it?

Comment: Yes. It's just a single class where I'm trying to reference it. It's odd that it works with standard .NET namespaces. I have System.Text.RegularExpressions imported at the top of my class and I'm able to reference the Regex class without the namespace. Seems like it should work with my class as well.

Comment: Are you importing both `MyWidget` and `MyWidget.MyWidget`, or are you saying that you have tried it with both individually and neither worked?

Comment: I tried both separately, and neither worked. Also, see my edit above. I tried it where the namespace and the class had different names, and I'm still not able to get it to work.

Comment: Don't import the class name.  Just import the namespace and then it will work.

Comment: That worked! Lesson of the day: Keep namespaces and class names different. Thanks @StevenDoggart!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the issue was the namespace and the class having the same name. After changing the namespace to `MyClasses` and the class to `MyWidget`, the following statements worked:

```
Imports MyClasses
```

...

```
Private widget as MyWidget
```

Answer (score 5):

Since the Namespace and Class have the same name the compiler gets confused when you try to instantiate MyWidget, despite the Imports statement.  Just because there is an Imports statement, doesn't mean you can't fully quanlify a type (even if you have Imports System.IO.File, you can still call System.IO.File.WriteAllText), thus the confusion on the compilers end.  An alternative would be to use an Alias.

```
Imports AWidget = MyWidget.MyWidget
```

Then..

```
Dim objWidget As New AWidget
```

Comment: Or, even better, don't use the same name for the class and the namespace.

Comment: I tried it with the namespace and the class having different names, and I'm still seeing the same results.